# Autocomplete list hides behind other controls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

In my rails application, user can add multiple patterns and allocate multiple locations to a particular pattern. The location is an autocomplete field.

**_pattern_form.html.erb**

```
<% f.fields_for:patterns do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'pattern_fields', :f => builder %>
<% end %>

<p class="add_fields"><%= link_to_add_patterns "Add Book", f, :patterns %></p>
```

**_pattern_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="fields" style="z-index: 1;">

    Pattern Pub: <%= f.select(:PAT_PUB, [['A', 'A'],
                     ['B', 'B'],
                     ['C', 'C']]) %>


    <div>    
      <% f.fields_for :location do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'location_fields', :f => builder %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

</div>
```

**_location_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field_with_auto_complete  :LCN_ADJACENT_TO , { :size => 55, :style=>" z-index:100;"}, { :url => formatted_locations_path(:js), :method => :get,  :skip_style => true, :param_name => 'search' } %>
```

The only problem is that when user types in the location autocomplete field, the autocomplete list is hidden behind the other pattern fields.

I created the following css and gave 'auto_complete' class an z-index of 100 but in vain.

```
.auto_complete {
    z-index: 100;
}

.auto_complete ul{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    background: #F0F8FF;
    z-index: 100;
}

.auto_complete li{
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 100;

}
```

Any suggestion on how to make the suggestion list appear on top of the page contents.

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). Other elements (your "pattern fields") should probably positioned too.

Comment: Just tried adding postion:absolute to the css but it's not doing anything

Comment: I slightly edited my answer, hopefully this is right this time. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, I will try playing with the positioning until it yields something :)